# How to call a polymorphic method in a thread object?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14

```cpp
struct Base {
    virtual void do_work() = 0;
};

struct Derived_A : Base {
    void do_work() override {
        // work A
    }
};

struct Derived_B : Base {
    void do_work() override {
        // work B
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> workers;
    workers.emplace_back(std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived_A()));
    workers.emplace_back(std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived_B()));

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (const auto& worker : workers) {
        // Compile error
        // expecting Derived_A and Derived_B do_work functions to be called respectively
        threads.emplace_back(&Base::do_work, worker);
    }
}
```

What is the right way to call the `do_work()` method in the thread?

Comment: `threads.emplace_back(&Base::do_work, std::ref(*worker));` compiles but need to investigate further regarding ownership of the smart pointer. live - https://godbolt.org/z/q3W7jejof

Comment: Re: `//Compile error` -- surely the compiler said more than that.

Comment: @PeteBecker to be fair to me, sometimes the compile time errors are hard to decipher.. anyway, after a complicated 'data structure' was displayed (visual c++ implementation), the final error was this  : "cannot convert argument 1 from '_Ty' to 'std::allocator_arg_t'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The polymorphism should *just work*, because a pointer to a virtual member function will always behave polymorphically when invoked. There are only two changes required to make your program correct:

1. You have to write `worker.get()` when creating the thread. This is because the pointer to member function `Base::do_work` is "invokable" with an argument that is a pointer to `Base`, but you can't "pass" a smart pointer to it directly.
2. You have to remember to either detach or join the threads before the end of `main`.